# Using decorators of optional dependency

Tags: python, python-import, python-decorators

Lets say I have the following code:

```
try:
    import bar
except ImportError:
    bar = None

@bar.SomeProvidedDecorator
def foo():
    pass
```

where *bar* is an optional dependency. The code above will fail, if bar isn't imported.
Is there a recommended way of dealing with this problem?

I came up with:

```
try:
    import bar
except ImportError:
    bar = None

def foo():
    pass

if bar is not None:
    foo = bar.SomeProvidedDecorator(foo)
```

but I'm wondering if there are better ways of handling this (i.e. is there a way to keep the decorator syntax) ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Provide an identity decorator in case of `bar` unavailability:

```py
try:
    import bar
except ImportError:
    class bar:
        SomeProvidedDecorator = lambda f: f
```

Comment: If there are lots of decorators in module `bar`, you could do something like defining `__getattr__` in your fallback class, e.g. `def __getattr(self, name)__: return lambda f: f`